# App (android) sencilla, va mas lenta en unos dispositivos(mas nuevos) que en otros(mas antiguos)

Tags: java, android, app

Estoy empezando a programar para android, y he hecho un juego de memoria, el de emparejar cartas iguales.

El juego va bien, no hay problemas de código, pero en las pruebas que hecho con los dispositivos que tengo en casa, veo que en un movil va mucho mas lento que en los otros dispositivos.
Es decir, lo he probado en un galaxy viejo y una tablet con jelly bean, una tablet con kitkat, una tablet con nougat, un samsung con nougat y un sony con marshmallow.

Lo curioso es que en los móviles mas nuevos (el sony m4 y el samsung A5) el juego va exageradamente lento, y en los otros va bien.

En cuanto al código, es sencillo. 
Hay varios layout con distinto numero de cartas para hacer parejas, de 8 a 32.
Cada carta consiste en un ImageView en el que le indico un fondo que hace de marco, y una imagen que hace del anverso de la carta.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/carta3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margenCartasJuego"
        android:padding="@dimen/paddinCartasJuego"
        android:background="@color/colorFondoCartasJuego"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        />
```

La logica es sencilla también.

De forma resumida.

Al iniciar la actividad asigna aleatoriamente las rutas de las distintas imágenes, por ejemplo:

1º- en una variable string llamada rutaCarta1 se le asigna la rutaFoto4.

2º- al ImageView con id carta1 se setea con setImageUri(Uri.parse(rutaCarta1)), también se escala con scaleType y se setea el alpha de la imagen a 0 para que no se vea la foto y se vea el src, que hace de anverso.

3º- al pulsar en la carta se setea el alpha de la imagen a 255 para que se vea, y se compara con la otra carta si la hay para ver si hacen pareja.

```
    carta1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            *//si es la segunda carta inhabilita el resto de cartas hasta    
            //que se comprueba si hacen pareja o no.*
            if(jugando){
                inhabilitarCartas();
            }
            //crea un hilo a parte para cambiar el alpha del ImageView.  
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        carta1.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                carta1.setImageAlpha(255);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
               *//añadí un retardo antes de llamar a la funcion que 
               //comprueba si hay pareja, para asegurarme que en el 
               //momento de ejecutar el hilo de cambiar el alpha no
               //habia mas código ejecutandose que le pudiera afectar.
               //
               //tanto el poner el código en un hilo a parte como el 
               //retardo ayudaron a que mostrase la imagen mas rápido.*

               retardoFuncionComprobarCarta(0);
            }
    });
```

Contra mas cartas haya en el layout mas lento va, las imágenes tiene un tamaño de entre 6 y 40kb.

En los móviles que va lento, se nota de forma exgerada que desde que pulsas hasta que se ve la imagen, pasan de 2 a 5 segundos, dependiendo del numero de cartas que tenga ese layout, en cambio, en los otros dispositivos es casi inmediato, y la diferencia entre el layout con 8 cartas y el de 32 es mínima.

He cambiado la forma de "destapar" la imagen varias veces con el mismo resultado (o peor), al principio no cambiaba el alpha a 0, y al pulsar la carta es cuando se seteaba la imagen con el setImageUri.

Espero haberme explicado bien.
Gracias.

---

Hola, revisando el código he encontrado la parte que mas relentiza el juego en los móviles nuevos.

Cuando destapa la segunda carta, llama a una función (inhabilitarCartas) que inhabilita todas las cartas para que no se pueda seguir jugando mientras se comprueba si hay pareja. Este es el código de la función:

```
public void inhabilitarCartas(){
    //inhabilita las cartas para que no se pueda pulsar mas cartas mientras se muestran la cartas
    // seleccionadas, para que el jugador pueda memorizar la posicion de estas cartas.

    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
        imageViewReseteoGeneral = (ImageView) findViewById(idCartas[i]);
        imageViewReseteoGeneral.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

He modificado el juego, añadiendo un condicionante a los eventos OnClickListener para solucionarlo.

```
    carta1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //comprueba si ya hay dos cartas giradas.
            //si no las hay, gira la carta y hace la comprobacion de pareja.Si hay dos cartas giradas, no hace nada.
            if(!comprobando){

                //si jugando es true, es que és la segunda carta seleccionada, y pone
                // comprobando en true para que no se ejecute otros onclicklistener.
                if(jugando){
                    comprobando=true;
                }
                //muestra la carta en un hilo a parte.
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        carta1.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                carta1.setImageAlpha(255);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

                //comprueba la carta.
                retardoFuncionComprobarCarta(0);
            }
            //si ya hay dos cartas giradas, no hace nada.
            else {
                return;
            }

        }
    });
```

Ahora va mas rápido, casi igual que en los otros dispositivos.

Pero sigo con la misma duda, y no sé porque, esta función relentiza el juego en los dispositivos que tienen mejor hardware y una versión de android mas nueva, y en los viejos o en las tablets funciona bien.

Gracias de nuevo.

Y feliz año.

Comment: Considero importante agregues el código para mostrar que realizas para realizar el cambio de las cartas.

Comment: gracias, voy ha añadir el código en la pregunta.

Comment: El ImageView lo cargas en algún ListView o RecyclerView?, podrías mostrar el código de tu adapter, además te recomiendo que uses el patrón ViewHolder para disminuir la carga de memoria.

Comment: El layout de juego consta, en el caso del de mas cartas, de 8 LinearLayout, y 4 ImageView cada LinearLayout. Baje el peso de la imagenes y mejoró. Pero lo que no acabo de entender es porque en un movil viejo de 4.2´´ o en una tablet vieja va bien , y en una tablet mas nueva con nougat también va bien, pero en los dos móviles mas potentes con nougat y marshmallow va mal.

Comment: Trata de hacer un clean desde gradle y luego un build. Eso eliminaría todo aquello que no hace falta.